# Strange result from pymc3 for small change in the variable

Tags: python, linear-regression, bayesian, pymc3

I have below model for which I seek estimation of parameters using `pymc3`

```python
import pandas as pd
import pymc3 as pm
import arviz as arviz

myData = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({
    'Unnamed: 0': {
        0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5, 5: 6, 6: 7, 7: 8, 8: 9, 9: 10,
        10: 11, 11: 12, 12: 13, 13: 14, 14: 15, 15: 16, 16: 17, 17: 18, 18: 19, 19: 20,
        20: 21, 21: 22, 22: 23, 23: 24, 24: 25, 25: 26, 26: 27, 27: 28, 28: 29, 29: 30, 
        30: 31, 31: 32, 32: 33, 33: 34, 34: 35, 35: 36, 36: 37, 37: 38}, 
    'y': {
        0: 0.0079235409492941, 1: 0.0086530073429249, 2: 0.0297400780486734, 3: 0.0196358416326437, 4: 0.0023902064076204, 5: 0.0258055591736283, 6: 0.17394835142698, 7: 0.156463554455613, 8: 0.329388185725557, 9: 0.0076443508881763, 
        10: 0.0162081480398152, 11: 0.0, 12: 0.0015759139941696, 13: 0.420025972703085, 14: 0.0001226236519444, 15: 0.133061480234834, 16: 0.565454216154227, 17: 0.0002819734812997, 18: 0.000559715156383, 19: 0.0270686389659072, 
        20: 0.918300537689865, 21: 7.8262468302e-06, 22: 0.0073241434191945, 23: 0.0, 24: 0.0, 25: 0.0, 26: 0.0, 27: 0.0, 28: 0.0, 29: 0.0, 
        30: 0.174071274611405, 31: 0.0432109713717948, 32: 0.0544400838264943, 33: 0.0, 34: 0.0907049925221286, 35: 0.616680102647887, 36: 0.0, 37: 0.0}, 
    'x': {
        0: 23.8187587698947, 1: 15.9991138359515, 2: 33.6495930512881, 3: 28.555818797764, 4: -52.2967967248258, 5: -91.3835208788233, 6: -73.9830692708321, 7: -5.16901145289629, 8: 29.8363012310241, 9: 10.6820057903939, 
        10: 19.4868517164395, 11: 15.4499668436458, 12: -17.0441644773509, 13: 10.7025053739577, 14: -8.6382953428539, 15: -32.8892974839165, 16: -15.8671863161348, 17: -11.237248036145, 18: -7.37978020066205, 19: -3.33500586334862, 
        20: -4.02629933182873, 21: -20.2413384726948, 22: -54.9094885578775, 23: -48.041459120976, 24: -52.3125732905322, 25: -35.6269065970458, 26: -62.0296155423529, 27: -49.0825017152659, 28: -73.0574478287598, 29: -50.9409090127938, 
        30: -63.4650928035253, 31: -55.1263264283842, 32: -52.2841103768755, 33: -61.2275334149805, 34: -74.2175990067417, 35: -68.2961107804698, 36: -76.6834643609286, 37: -70.16769103228}
    })

with pm.Model() as myModel :
    beta0 = pm.Normal('intercept', 0, 1)
    beta1 = pm.Normal('x', 0, 1)
    mu = beta0 + beta1 * myData['x'].values
    pm.Bernoulli('obs', p = pm.invlogit(mu), observed = myData['y'].values)

with myModel :
    calc = pm.sample(50000, tune = 10000, step = pm.Metropolis(), random_seed = 1000)

arviz.summary(calc, round_to = 10)

               mean        sd    hdi_3%   hdi_97%  mcse_mean   mcse_sd      ess_bulk      ess_tail     r_hat
intercept -2.537501  0.599667 -3.707061 -1.450243   0.004375  0.003118  18893.344191  22631.772985  1.000070
x          0.033750  0.024314 -0.007871  0.081619   0.000181  0.000133  18550.620475  20113.739639  1.000194
```

Now I changed above model to this,

```
mu = beta0 + beta1 * myData['x'].values * 0
```

With this change I get below result,

```
               mean        sd    hdi_3%   hdi_97%  mcse_mean   mcse_sd      ess_bulk      ess_tail     r_hat
intercept -2.690874  0.546570 -3.698465 -1.643091   0.003611  0.002565  22980.471424  24806.935727  1.000036
x         -0.013861  1.003612 -1.916176  1.826709   0.006874  0.005175  21336.662537  23299.680306  1.000084
```

I wonder if above estimate is correct. Should not I expect very small estimate for the coefficient `beta1`? I see hardly any change for this estimate except just change in sign.

Any pointer is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> "*hardly any change for this estimate*"

Seems like you are ignoring the `sd`, which has a strong change and is behaving as expected. That is, the first version yields `0.034 ± 0.024` (weakly positive); whereas the second correctly reverts to the prior with `-0.014 ± 1.00`.

Looking at the input data, none of this seems surprising:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Can you please help me understand, how exactly `pymc3` build the `Likelihood function` for this type of model?

Comment: @Bogaso the likelihood is the evaluation of the data on the observed variable(s).

Comment: Actually my question was how `likelihood function` is constructed in this case? Can I get a simplified expression of `likelihood function` for this case of fractional data, how `pymc3` constructed?

Comment: @Bogaso sorry, I still don't get what is misunderstood. However, it seems like possibly outside the scope of the original question. If you need further clarification on specifically my answer please say so. The main point is: when you don't link the prior parameter to the data, it will simply sample the prior with no what the data - that is what is happening with the model without the intercept.

Comment: Thanks for your response. However what I was asking is, it is not clear to me how exactly `pymc3` construct the `likelihood function` if the response variable is `proportional` in nature and user wants to fit `Factional regression model` on such that like this example. Do you know if there is any material/reference which discusses this?

Comment: That’s more a methodological question (definitely outside scope of the original question). For cases where proportions are directly observed, then the immediate model is a Beta regression. Search and you will find. A common alternative model is Normal regression with a logit transformed observations. You can ask a new question if you need help with implementing.

Comment: Not PyMC3, but this is an excellent demo on Bayesian Beta Regression: https://www.andrewheiss.com/blog/2021/11/08/beta-regression-guide/